# Unable to restore RocksDb state on PVC when the job manager restarts

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I'm using a KeyedCoProcess Function to connect 2 streams from Kafka and persisting them in the Flink Value State, both of these streams are having a common key ( which is used to access the state.). Messages arrive on the first Kafka topic then they're persisted into the state by the through the key and when the message from the other topic arrives with the same key, it is looked up in the state and enriched and forwarded to another kafka topic.
I am using RocksDbStateBackend to store the state onto the PVC. The issue that I'm facing is, the entire state is lost if the job manager restarts. Apart from that the expired state is not getting cleaned up from PVC as well. Attaching code samples and configurations.

Job Config

```
    EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend embeddedRocksDb = new EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend();
    embeddedRocksDb.setDbStoragePath("path/to/pvc/mount_path");
    env.setStateBackend(embeddedRocksDb);
    env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointStorage("checkpointing-location"));
    env.enableCheckpointing(1000))));
```

PVC config

```
podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: flink-main-container
          env:
          volumeMounts:
            - name: efs-claim
              mountPath: "/data/flink/state"
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      volumes:
        - name: efs-claim
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: efs-claim
```

state config

```
private ValueStateDescriptor<XX>> getValueDesc() {
        StateTtlConfig timeToLive = StateTtlConfig
                .newBuilder(Time.minutes(1440))
                .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
                .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
                .cleanupInRocksdbCompactFilter(this.queryTimeAfterNumEntries)
                .build();
        descriptor.enableTimeToLive(timeToLive);
        return descriptor;
    }
```

I'm not using savepoints and the topology of the job remains same before and after the restart.
Kindly help. Let me know if there's some information apart from this needed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Asked in the Speedb hive and this is the answer I got for you:

"The only reason that I can think of that the rocksdb data will be lost is writing without WAL . We can look at the rocksdb LOG to ensure,  but you need to ask for help in the Flink support"

Have you tried asking in the Flink server on Slack?
If you'd like to send us your logs, join the Hive [here](https://discord.gg/72MRDXYTV8) and reply in the thread about your question -